# Selecting MAX from a COUNT

Tags: sql, web-sql

It's been a couple of years since I have had to do some more complicated SQL and I'm a bit rusty. I need to select a `max(count())`, but I have recently re-learned that you can't nest aggregate functions.

I am using WebSQL and have a Table called "calls".

```
Calls
  id INT
  targetId INT
  date DATETIME
```

I need to select the maximum COUNT of the target id. So far I have this:

```
SELECT targetId, COUNT(targetId) AS NumberOfCalls FROM calls GROUP BY targetId
```

This is returning to me the number of times each target has been called. I need to dynamically build a report around this and will need to know the highest value that any of the targetIds have

I tried this but it isn't working and returns no data to me whatsoever:

```
SELECT MAX(x.count) FROM (SELECT COUNT(targetId) AS count FROM calls GROUP BY targetId)   x
```

If anyone could help me out, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a count of the number of times that a targetid shows up in the table, and then the max value from that. This will give you that:

SELECT MAX(NumberOfCalls) FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(*) as NumberOfCalls FROM calls GROUP BY targetid
   )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn the maximum ID of selected targetId, try this :

```
SELECT targetId, MAX(targetId) AS MaxTargetId FROM calls GROUP BY targetId
```